# How to use AnyClass to init an specific class instance in swift3.x

Tags: swift, init

> I have seen this question on stackoverflow [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119501/how-to-convert-anyclass-to-a-specific-class-and-init-it-dynamically-in-swift)  Unfortunately, this answer is not helpful in swift3.x

```
protocol Effect {

    func des()
}

class A: Effect {

    func des() {
        print("This is A")
    }

    required init() { }
}

class B: Effect {

    func des() {
        print("This is B")
    }

    required init() { }
}
```

I want to store class A & B in an array

```
var array = [Effect.Type]()
array.append(A.self)
array.append(B.self)
```

When I want to get class A & B from array, I get this result

```
A.self   // __lldb_expr_23.A.Type
A.self.init().des() -> This i A
array[0] // __lldb_expr_23.A.Type
array[0].init().des() -> Error
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RoK2.png)

I know I can use this method to init Class A

```
let a = array[0] as! A.Type
a.init().des() -> This is class A
```

But if I don't know the class exactly, I cannot init the class by Effect.Type
So How  to use AnyClass to init an specific class instance without use as! ... in Swift3.x?

Comment: Are you wanting to store an array of Types? Or of instances of objects?

Comment: I want to store an array of Types? And then use these Types to init instances of objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `init()` as requirement to the protocol definition
in order to call it on the array values of type `Effect.Type`:

```
protocol Effect {
    init()
    func des()
}
```

Then everything works as expected:

```
let array: [Effect.Type] = [ A.self, B.self ]

array[0].init().des() // This is A
array[1].init().des() // This is B
```

Comment: It works. But why must I add init() in the protocol? Is the reason that Effect.Type cannot Analysis the method init()?

Comment: @pluto: How else could the compiler know that all types conforming to `Effect` have an `init()` method?

Comment: Ok, I understand